# Typo3 mask extension grid element creation

Tags: typo3, extbase, tx-mask

I'm new to typo3 mask extension.I need a three column grid and it should contain another mask CE. Is it possible? Im using the very last version of mask 3.0.1 and typo3 version 8.7.4 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be no problem. just use three fields of type content, where you enable the appropriate CEs at `Allowed content elements`.

The rendering in the template is as usual. for the content of the first column use: (assumed you named the field of your first column `my_col1`)

```
<f:if condition="{data.tx_mask_my_col1}">
    <f:for each="{data.tx_mask_my_col1}" as="data_item">
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_mask.content">{data_item.uid}</f:cObject>
    </f:for>
</f:if>
```